# Bug on the reputation page

Tags: bug, reputation

How could I reached the cap with upvotes only more than the times I got *at least 200* rep :

> days represented 168
>   rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 14 days
>   earned at least 200 reputation on 13 days
>   earned 0 reputation from suggested edits

So...

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 14 days

This line means I got 200 from Upvotes only so this is eligible in the badge progress.

> earned at least 200 reputation on 13 days

This is all the times I got 200 rep regardless.

I mean on the 14th day were I got 200 from upvotes... didn't I reached at least 200 ?

Comment: That is basically what my answer says @insertcleverxmasname :-)

Answer (score 3):

You hit the rep cap.

That does not mean that you earned 200 rep on that day.

So in other words you *hit* the rep cap, but then your rep went down for some reason from downvotes or something else

Comment: How can you reach the 200 rep cap without getting 200 rep ?

Comment: See the last line of my answer @insertcleverxmasname

Comment: @insert 200(rep capped) -2=198

Comment: Yep, @insertcleverxmasname it usually happens when you place a bounty.  And indeed, two days ago you reached rep cap and placed a bounty of 50 points, resulting in total of 198 points. Your actual rep should have been 248 which is 200 from upvotes + 45 from 3 accepted answers + 2 from accepting an answer to your question + 1 I can't explain. :)